# is it possible to use strong swan to set host to host vpn for many clients which have dynamic ips?

Tags: ipsec, strongswan

I want my server to set a vpn connection for each client trying to connect, where clients would usually have dynamic addresses.

Most importantly, is it possible to do this with unique psk given for each client without using certificates?